# How to capture full screen in c using visual studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

Is it possible to capture full screen in visual studio (VC++), so that user don't have to press ATL+Enter. Kindly guide me how I can make it possible.

Comment: I do not fully understand the question. Could you elaborate? Do you wish to capture a screenshot in C or C++ or do you wish to enter full screen mode in Visual Studio without pressing [Alt] Enter?

Comment: I want to enter in full screen mode.

Comment: Is there any reason why Alt-Enter would not work..?

Comment: Alt+Enter is working, but I want that my application default mode should be full screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to enter fullscreen mode in OpenGL per default, check out NeHe Productions, for instance his [second lesson](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=02)
If you download his example at the bottom of the screen and check out the:
`BOOL CreateGLWindow(char* title, int width, int height, int bits, bool fullscreenflag)`
.. you will see how it can be made in OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you are using `Direct3D` alt-enter enters full screen mode by default.

If your application is "normal" (ie, not a 3d application) then there is no actual full-screen mode. You can however create the illusion of it by maximizing the window and removing things like the top menu bar.